# Best practice to isolate OS and packages per use case

Tags: ubuntu, centos, filesystems, configuration

I would like the following setup (Ubuntu, CentOS, but willing to use any modern distro)

- OS is self contained (OS is OS, not the mess of OS+DB+Apache+etc + hundreds of libraries only one application uses)
- use case A has its files completely separated (e.g. IntelliJ and other packages installed in /opt)
- use case B has its files completely separated (e.g. Database server and supporting packages in /opt)
- use case C,D, ...

The idea is that

- I could replace/upgrade the OS version without any side effect to everything else
- Applications are installed in /opt without any side effect to the OS, e.g. I run a script in /opt that adjusts PATH and other settings.
- I could (exclusively) mount case A files to /opt/work and do Java work
- I could (exclusively) mount case B files to /opt/work and do SQL work

Notice that apt/yum just messes up OS installs with files that should not be actually installed with the OS (e.g. because I need to use different versions of libraries). Also, files in /etc are changed.

Solutions like snap work on package level, and because of that, PATH gets rather large, and file lookups and startup time are longer. Also, snap packages are many times of unknown origin/packager, and the quality and security is questionable (PPA is the death of security). The idea is good though (having a separate path and having ${BASE_PATH}/{bin,lib,etc} for each use case.

The overall goal is:

- complete control over the OS (security, auditing, automated upgrading and versioning without manual intervention)
- complete control of development environments (versioning, upgrades, offline package installs, etc.)
- yet complete access to Wayland and GUI and other native acceleration features.

I know I could run application in Docker, but GUI access needs root, that I don't like. I do not have too much experience with Podman for rootless X. I also could start a VM, but that requires a processor with proper support, and for example most of EC2 instances do not support running a VM inside a VM. The question is not specific to EC2 though.

Comment: "but GUI access needs root" not necessarily: X needs a unix domain socket, OpenGL etc. acceleration needs more (e.g. device files, depends on the hardware). All can run without root. But it's not straightforward to set this up on Docker. I'd also question the use case where you'd want different *GUI applications* in different containers, that just feels wrong. You want *one* environment for a user with a GUI, not several.

Comment: Yes, X needs from Docker container access to the socket, but that is run as root, and requires additional privileges for the container. Also, this weakens the security posture, as exploitable X bugs result in immediate root access.

Your second comment challenges the requirement, instead of solving it :-). If some of the development is on a sensitive IP (NDA-d), you want to limit exposure as much as possibe. The ideal setup completely avoids any visibility from other tools.

Also, with this setup, you can for example NFS mount different setup for different users.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a distribution designed with these usage patterns in mind, such as [Fedora Silverblue](https://silverblue.fedoraproject.org/). You can keep the base OS as a read-only system, upgraded “en masse” when necessary, and run all your services and applications in sandboxed environments (but with full access to the display server).

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Based on the description, this is likely a good fit, I will try it out right away. One more question: do you know if this type of immutable setup eventually arrive in RHEL?

Comment: There’s RHEL CoreOS, but I think that’s only available as part of OpenShift.

Comment: I used CoreOS before, but that was mainly a clean OS with heavily locked down security for containerization. But since the RHEL acquisition, things might have changed, I will have another look, thanks!

Comment: No, nothing much has changed, it’s still a base OS, not really intended for desktop use...

Comment: I will accept this answer, as it handles most of the issues listed in the Question. I will either use this OS or will replicate the design choices it implements, and aside of this I will use SELinux to further control access to files, network, etc. Thank you again for your answer !

Comment: As a matter of fact, Silverblue uses Podman for workspace isolation (so does not circumvent contanerization), Flatpack for application isolation (there are some very shady Flatpack packages out there, similarly to snap) so the real deal here is RPM-ostree, which is a good solution for OS immutability and transactional updates.

Comment: I have unaccepted this answer as Flatpak is more than shady. See e.g.  [https://flatkill.org](https://flatkill.org/), [FlatKill update 2020](https://flatkill.org/2020/). (Also see [CVE scores](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/38446/Flatpak-Flatpak.html?vendor_id=16613).) It may become a mature solution, but I would rather not risk exposing confidential information.

Comment: Also note that security issues come from incorrect (too permissive) packaging, lack of updates, poorly maintained Flatpak packages, etc.

Answer (score 2):

CentOS or Fedora - I would install podman:

`sudo yum -y install podman`

https://podman.io/getting-started/

> What is Podman? Podman is a daemonless container engine for developing, managing, and running OCI Containers on your Linux System. Containers can either be run as root or in rootless mode. Simply put: alias docker=podman. More details here.

https://podman.io/

Comment: Thanks! I am not very knowledgeable of how Podman handles direct memory mapping and other features that are required for efficient IPC. This is on my list as a fallback solution (and even Docker - I use Docker extensively), but I believe a correctly configured Linux should be able to do what I described without resorting to containerization.